# HTML5 how to access front camera on device (iPad or Nexus tablet)

Tags: android, ios, html, tablet, front-camera

knowing that by using this HTML tag:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

it's possible to open the primary camera on device, i would ask if it's possible open directly the front camera of Apple or Android tablet device..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I know there is no way to open the camera from the browser, if you will like to take advantage of the iphone/android camera you should learn about android or iphone SDK.